# MySQL query for wordpress meta data

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need some help with a query that should return posts based on their wp-postratings score (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postratings/).

The user chooses a minimum rating (0 to 5 stars) and a maximum rating (0 to 5 stars) and the query should return the posts that match. I have it working where the user input for both values is above 0 but I can't seem to get my head around the 0 value. Since 0 represents unrated posts - and hence onces that have no ratings meta data - I need to select not only the posts where the rating is no more than the specified max value, but also every post that has no rating meta data.

How can I do this?? Any help will be very much appreciated!

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*, (t1.meta_value+0.00) AS ratings_average, (t2.meta_value+0.00) AS ratings_users, (t3.meta_value+0.00) AS ratings_score 
FROM wp_posts p 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON  t.term_id = tt.term_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS t1 ON t1.post_id = p.ID 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS t2 ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS t3 ON t3.post_id = p.ID 
WHERE t1.meta_key = 'ratings_average' 
AND t2.meta_key = 'ratings_users' 
AND t3.meta_key = 'ratings_score' 
AND p.post_date < NOW() 
AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
AND (tt.taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND tt.term_id = t.term_id AND t.slug = 'liverpool')
AND ( (t1.meta_value+0.00) IS NULL OR (t1.meta_value+0.00) <= $max_stars )
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this query seems to work for me. Its a bit ugly though and not too quick so if anyone has a better one feel free to improve upon it!

It selects all of the rated posts that are below the $max_stars value, then combines the table with a separate select which gets all of the non-rated posts:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT p.*, (t1.meta_value+0.00) AS ratings_average, (t2.meta_value+0.00) AS ratings_users, (t3.meta_value+0.00) AS ratings_score 
FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON  t.term_id = tt.term_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS t1 ON t1.post_id = p.ID 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS t2 ON t2.post_id = p.ID 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS t3 ON t3.post_id = p.ID 
WHERE t1.meta_key = 'ratings_average' 
AND t2.meta_key = 'ratings_users' 
AND t3.meta_key = 'ratings_score' 
AND p.post_date < NOW() 
AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
AND (tt.taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND tt.term_id = t.term_id AND t.slug = 'liverpool')
AND (t1.meta_value+0.00) <= $max_stars )

UNION

(SELECT DISTINCT p.*, NULL AS ratings_average, NULL AS ratings_users, NULL AS ratings_score 
FROM wp_posts p 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON  t.term_id = tt.term_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS t1 ON (t1.post_id = p.ID AND t1.meta_key = 'ratings_score')
WHERE t1.post_id is null
AND p.post_date < NOW() 
AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
AND (tt.taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND tt.term_id = t.term_id AND t.slug = 'liverpool') )

ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar a while back where I was running a cron job to send posts to another application that weren't already registered. The best method I found was to write a query that checked that the ID was NOT IN a query of posts with the meta key.

```
SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID
FROM $wpdb->posts 
WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
AND $wpdb->posts.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    left join $wpdb->postmeta ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'meta_key')
```

I believe this should work, though I obviously haven't tested it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*, (t1.meta_value+0.00) AS ratings_average, (t2.meta_value+0.00) AS ratings_users, (t3.meta_value+0.00) AS ratings_score
FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS t1 ON t1.post_id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS t2 ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS t3 ON t3.post_id = p.ID
WHERE t1.meta_key = 'ratings_average'
AND t2.meta_key = 'ratings_users'
AND t3.meta_key = 'ratings_score'
AND p.post_date < NOW()
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
AND (tt.taxonomy = 'post_tag' 
AND tt.term_id = t.term_id 
AND t.slug = 'liverpool')
AND ( 
p.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT p.ID 
    FROM wp_posts AS p
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm ON (pm.post_id = p.ID)
    WHERE pm.meta_key = 'ratings_score'
)
OR 
(t1.meta_value+0.00) <= $max_stars )
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately this query only returns those that have been rated.